# Running juju, how do you edit files?

Tags: windows, juju, ftp, wordpress

Juju does not associate keyfiles with the instances it creates, so you cannot ssh with them. I tried connecting with filezilla using port 22 (open) using the username juju-admin and the admin-secret found in environments.yaml and it did not work. I would like to edit some of the wordpress content files. I am running on ec2 with nfs charm associated to wordpress.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah... windows client.

There is a free ssh client called PuTTY.

It is possible that the client allowed you to create instances that have no authorized keys.  Check this by running:

```
juju get-env authorized-keys
```

You may need to create a key pair using PuTTY, and add the public key to the authorized-keys. Unfortunately this wouldn't help any machines already running.

Probably best to just destroy that environment and start another one.

Comment: Okay, i created a small instance with ubuntu, lxde, and xrdp. I remote into that for juju bootstrap and everything works fine. I stop it when I'm not using it so it costs me next to nothing for the convenience. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Is there a way to create a vsftpd user with full root privileges? How do most people edit files created by juju?

Answer (score 2):

By running `juju status` you can get the name of the machine ex) `wordpress/0` You can then ssh into that machine using `juju ssh wordpress/0`.

The `juju status` command also gives you the ip address, among other data, of the machine so you can create ssh tunnels and the like with ease.

In order to FTP into your ec2 machine you will need to install an ftp server such as `vsftpd` on your machine. There is also a charm https://jujucharms.com/fullscreen/search/precise/vsftpd-1/?text=ftp which you can deploy to your wordpress node using the details here https://jujucharms.com/docs/stable/charms-deploying#deploying-to-specific-machines-and-containers

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to set up ftp through a client such as filezilla? My main issue with scp is it is so difficult to mentally keep track of where every relevant file is in the folder hierarchy and what its exact name.

Comment: I have updated the answer to include details about setting up an ftp server.

Comment: Hate to keep bugging you, but I can't get it to work. I deployed wordpress and vsftpd to the same machine. I added a user and password to vsftpd. But login to ftp via port 21 fails in both filezilla and browser. Browser login just fails to connect, filezilla connects, gets welcome message etc, then switching to binary, pasv, econnaborted. Is there any additional set up for vsftpd other than that which is available via the charm's config in juju-gui?

Comment: Also, should add vsftpd is exposed and nothing else is on that node.

Comment: and "juju ssh wordpress/0" fails with "ERROR exec: "ssh": executable file not found in %PATH%"